# Не могу пройти авторизацию на гос. услугах

Tags: python, selenium, auth, госуслуги

Использую selenium но не могу пройти авторизацию на гос. услугах. После ввода данных нажатии "вход" или enter страница начинает загружаться, но вновь прогружается страница входа. Смотрю что приходи в /login и вижу только приходящую ошибку 302. Если пытаюсь зайти средством ручного ввода - то все заходит без проблем. Помогите понять как обойти это. headless не думаю что подойдет, ведь цель не парсинг, а авторизация на сайте, чтобы другой человек мог зайти в профиль гос. услуг не видя логина и пароля. Зайти таким образом нужно, чтобы вытащить cookies сессии, благодаря которым потом будет происходить вход скрывая лог и пароль. На случай если я далеко, а кукесы уже не проходят - тогда другое доверенное лицо будет снова запускать процесс авторизации и сохранение куксов. Поэтому нужен такой велосипед. Я не очень опытный человек в этом и поэтому есть еще вопрос: Сколько проживут cookies которые я заберу при первой авторизации? Насколько я понимаю - через время они перестают действовать.(Если я пишу глупости, извините)
Ну код и так понятно, что максимально простой

Comment: _приходящую ошибку 302_ 302 - это не ошибка, а редирект на госуслуги, где надо пройти авторизацию, после чего госусулуги редиректнут обратно на сайт с кодом авторизации, бэк сайта сходит на госуслуги с этим кодом и получит токен, дальше сайт проверит токен и вернет свой токен и т.д. Не думаю, что сработает _максимально простой_ код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все максимально просто. Я убил весь день, чтобы понять как это обойти. И знаете как это получилось сделать? Сложный код? Подменные cookies? Неееет. Нужно просто снова заполнить поля авторизации и все готово. Как оказалось можно просто сразу же вставить лог и пароль второй раз, и гос. услуги пускают на свой сайт.